Ways to automatically reboot Raspberry Pi daily
My Raspberry Pi restarts daily, but I don't remember how I set it up. And I need to change the schedule.
There is nothing in crontab:
crontab -l

What are other ways to automatically restart Raspberry Pi?

See if systemctl list-timers --all rings any bells.

I hope it helps. https://sukhbinder.wordpress.com/2023/04/02/reboot-raspberry-pi-every-time-on-schedule/

There are 2 crontabs -- user crontab and system crontab. Make sure to check both.
crontab -l
sudo crontab -l

